# When the digits in the number $2005$ are reversed we obtain the number $5002$, and $5002 = a \cdot b \cdot c$, such that $a$, $b$ and $c$

Tags: number-theory

> When the digits in the number $2005$ are reversed we obtain the number $5002$, and $5002 = a \cdot b \cdot c$, such that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are three distinct primes. How many other positive integers are the products of exactly three distinct primes $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ such that $p_1 + p_2 + p_3 = a+b+c$?

---

I'm not sure how to approach this. I found that $a, b, c$ are $2, 41, 61$. Since there is only $1$ even prime, the other two primes must be odd. But short of going through every combination of primes that sum to $41+61=102$, how can I cleverly find the answer?

Thanks!

---

The answer to this is $\boxed{7}.$

Comment: There aren't many primes smaller than $102$. Going through every combination is the clever way. There's a small difference in efficiency depending on whether you start with the large prime or the small one.

Comment: Ok. I was just wondering if there was a faster way, like if the sum was larger or something.

Comment: What is the purpose of the fact that $5002$ is the reverse of $2005$ in the problem statement?

Comment: I have no idea...

Comment: @JohnDouma I suspect the question was created for a contest (or maybe as a homework) in 2005 (or possibly in December 2004). For unfathomable reasons, some people find "this year occurs in the problem text" cute/funny/delightful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $5002 = 2\cdot 41\cdot 61$ and $2+41+61=104$. We need to partition $104$ into three distinct primes, which means we need two odd primes and one (the only) even prime.

So partitioning $102 = 2\cdot3\cdot 17$  into two primes; probably the easiest way is descending through the sparser higher primes, if you remember those; otherwise work up, it's not hugely different.

$101+1 \quad\!\color{red}{\Large\times}$ (maybe too obvious $\ddot\smile$)
$97+5 \;\quad\color{green}\checkmark$ (and $97\cdot 5 \cdot 2 = 970$, etc.)
$89+13 \quad\color{green}\checkmark$
$83+19 \quad\color{green}\checkmark$
$79+23 \quad\color{green}\checkmark$
$73+29 \quad\color{green}\checkmark$
$71+31 \quad\color{green}\checkmark$
$67+35 \quad\!\color{red}{\Large\times}$
$61+41 \quad\checkmark$ (but already used)
$59+43 \quad\color{green}\checkmark$
$53+49 \quad\!\color{red}{\Large\times}$

giving $7$ alternatives, as you found.